# How do I get the corresponding frequency values to my data after FFT?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I have the following dataset in normal space, lets call it `func`:[image]
I transformed it to fourierspace using the numpy fft algorithm `from numpy.fft import fft as fourier`, I received the fouriertransform using`func_fourier = np.fft.fftshift(fourier(func))` and plotted the absolute values `plt.plot(np.abs(func_fourier))`, what results in the following plot:[image].

I now want to fit a gaussian model to this function in fourierspace. The problem is, that I dont have x-values(frequencies) that I could plot my `func_fourier` over. How do I create the correct frequency array in fourierspace, which I also need for fitting the gaussian model to my transformed function ?

Comment: how did you plot your `func` ? maybe a range `400-2000` is used ? then what is the sampling rate used ? see [numpy.fft.fftfreq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html)

Comment: Did you search for the issue? What did you get?

Answer (score -1):

The default x-values are created as follows:

```
frequencies = list(range(len(y)))
```

Note: According to your explanation, your Fourier transformed values are stored in func_fourier, so the y is `func_fourier`.

Comment: you mean the default x-values in the plt.plot() function, that are created if you leave out the first argument, like plt.plot(y) ?

Comment: @trynerror I was out of the office, so I was unable to edit the comment. See the updated answer.